# Why do vectors have arrowheads at the "endpoint"?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

In high school math, we were taught to recognize a line with an arrow at its head as a ray. Vectors are basically just line segments with direction, aren't they? So why do they look like rays?

Comment: Gotta draw them somehow. What would you have preferred?

Comment: And what they should have at the end? A flower?

Comment: It's not quite right to say that a vector is basically just a line segment with direction, because any two directed line segments with the same length and the same direction are representatives of the same vector.  (Also note that the word "vector" is used to mean different but related things in math; for example "vector" often just means an $n$-tuple of numbers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These pictures that you draw with arrows and arrowheads are representations of abstract mathematical objects.

A **ray** is a subset of a line that has a starting point and extends indefinitely in one direction (not the other).  The arrowhead is meant to indicate that *it goes on and on.*  The length of the arrow is completely irrelevant since the ray is infinite in length.

A **vector** is mathematical gadget that keeps track of both *magnitude* (think size) and *direction*.  It's useful for keeping track of things like velocity, which has a magnitude (*speed*) and a direction.  An arrow is a nice way to indicate this because the length of the arrow tells you about the magnitude, and the direction that it points in tells you about direction.

Sometimes, you'll see a vector in the plane described by an ordered pair (which makes it look like a point).  For example, $\vec{v} = (2, 1)$ tells you that the vector points in a direction $2$ to the right and $1$ up.  You can picture this by drawing an arrow (a line *segment* with an arrowhead) beginning at the origin $(0, 0)$ and ending at $(2, 1)$.

But, the crucial idea behind vectors is that *they don't have to begin at the origin*.  The arrow that you draw from, say, the point $(1, 4)$ to $(3, 5)$ is also the vector $\vec{v} = (2, 1)$ since the $x$ and $y$ components are
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x &= 3 - 1 = 2, \\
y &= 5 - 4 = 1.
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The takeaway here is that what you have learned in high school math is a matter of notational convention for the sake of the teachers' well-being, and not your own education. There are many cases where "a line with an arrow at the end of it" has nothing to do with a ray.

For instance, consider $f : X \to Y$. The $\to$ in this case is not a ray -- it is a shorthand way of saying the function $f$ maps elements of $X$ to elements of $Y$.

Now, you may argue, "but this is written math; I am talking about diagrams."

Well then, how about [commutative diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_diagram)?

But then you say, "no no, I am talking about graphs."

So, like a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)?

But then you might argue, "no, like drawing a function."

But vectors aren't functions, so drawing a vector has little to do with graphing functions at all.

In the end, this is rectifiable by making the following argument: we have a finite number of practical symbols that we can use, and we cannot omit context from our use of those symbols. Whilst a line with an arrow may mean a ray in elementary geometry, we do not necessarily use that definition when dealing with vector arithmetic.

The statement "in math, a line with an arrow at the end means that the object is a ray" is not only patently false, but it promotes a deleterious and even dangerous mindset that mathematics is a universal truth, arguable only by people with the mental wherewithal to deal with arcane rules, symbology, and scriptures. Whilst that latter claim [may sometimes be true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), the truth is that typeset and written notational conventions are some of the least complicated and least restrictive elements of math.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally three properties - length, direction, **orientation**. 
E.g. $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ share length and direction, but not orientation. So, that's a way of distinguishing between them.

Comment: That's an interesting way to break down the information of a vector.  However, it's more common to use a stricter notion of *direction,* for which $(1, 0)$ and $(-1, 0)$ point in **opposite** directions.  That way, there's no need to include the additional *orientation* (which usually means something different in mathematics).

Comment: I see, I had this problem during high school, because in Czech we say exactly those three properties, and I was like: "What is the difference between **direction** and **orientation**?" Because the intuition is (I would say) almost the same - I would imagine directions as e.g. pointing somebody to something ("Go in this direction.") where it already contains the information (going back $\neq$ going forward). And orientation is like standing in the center of a circle and turning around. But I somehow got used to this terms.

Comment: Also I wanted to include the fact, that vectors may lay everywhere in the space, but did not know the proper terms. In my native language we use something, that could be translated as _free_  vector (can be everywhere) and _binded_ vector (is glued by one end, commonly to the origin).

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\vec{AB}$ is used to denote the displacement of $B$ relative to $A$, i.e. the vector from $A$ to $B$. Clearly $\vec{AB}=-\vec{BA}$, hence the direction of the arrow has significance. However the notation $\vec{v}$, although popular, is unnecessary as the arrow has no significance. The symbol $\underline{v}$ is preferred to denote a vector quantity to be distinguished from scalar quantity (no underline), or a matrix quantity.